# Pass list javascript in parameter ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have a modal with input, i digit some emails and add to a list, later i  want to pass this list of emails  to my function that send emails.

```
        var listEmails = [];
    document.getElementById("addEmail").onclick = function () {

        var text = document.getElementById("recipient-email").value;

        $("#Listmail").append('<li>' + text + '</li>');

        listEmails.push(text);

    }

    document.getElementById("sendEmail").onclick = function () {


       @*location.href = '@Url.Action("TestSendReport", "ProductMarketplace")?emails='+listEmails;

    }
```

that is my function in Controller that receive a list of email to send

```
         public void TestSendReport(List<string> ListMails)
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `jQuery` with `HttpPost`?

Comment: im new on this javascript

Comment: It is very basic in ASP.NET MVC. I suggest you to watch [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals) free PluralSight Video by Scott Allen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code and try to call controller method using jQuery Ajax

```
    var list= [];
document.getElementById("addEmail").onclick = function () {

    var text = document.getElementById("recipient-email").value;

    $("#Listmail").append('<li>' + text + '</li>');

    list.push(text);

}

document.getElementById("sendEmail").onclick = function () {
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ list: list});

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ProductMarketplace/TestSendReport",
            data: jsonText,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function() { alert("success"); },
            failure: function() { alert("failed"); }
        });

}
```

And use controller method like this,

```
[WebMethod]
        public void TestSendReport(List<string> list)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("sendEmail").onclick = function () {
   location.href = '@Url.Action("TestSendReport", "ProductMarketplace")?emails=' + 
      encodeURI(JSON.stringify(listEmails));
}

public void TestSendReport(List<string> emails)
{
}
```

Comment: thx  but still not pass my list my method receive a empety list